# how to build a remote file explorer in a flex app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, file

I'd like my users to be able to easily navigate their files, which live on my server. Is there an obvious / built in way to build the front end for this in Flex? My ideal scenario would be to have something that looks like the local file browser - but I'm pretty sure that's not an option (although I'd love to be wrong). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

thank you!

f

Edited: sorry if this sounds to broad. Let me try to make it a bit more specific: assume all the back-end stuff is taken care of and I have all the data on my local machine. Are there any good flex components to easily navigate a list of files in a way that is familiar to users? A tree structure is a good idea. A datagrid may also work. I was wondering if there examples of something more out there. thanks!

Comment: your question is very broad and thus rather hard to answer, can you perhaps narrow it's scope a little bit?

Comment: ok, tried to make it less broad in scope - hope it makes more sense. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have services exposing the file system tree, there shouldn't be any problem.
You can use the Tree component in Flex (probably with a ITreeDataDescriptor) to render the file system structure

Answer (score 0):

While the tree component is fine, you can just create your own item renderers and use flash.net.socket

Start here:
http://ted.onflash.org/2007/05/flexftp-ftp-client-in-flex-using.php

view source and all that fun stuff.